# Kendo Angular 2 Grid and Async Pipe

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to implement something similar to the grid demo where it shows to use the async pipe with the data binding. I've bound to a service where I provide an observable GridDataResult.... and it works fine... BUT, when the data changes, my grid does not automatically refresh. I have to mouse over or click the grid for it to recognize the data changes that occurred to the observable. ??? I've tried it a few different ways, all with the same result. Anyone else experience this / run into this?

Thanks in advance!
-Brian

Comment: One additional comment... if I add a ChangeDetectorRef reference, and then call detectChanges, the grid will update correctly. I can do this during the subscription update of the observable, but I'm not sure if it really is a good practice / good idea to do regularly when I work on refreshing a grid...

Comment: I have got that running. Can you share some Code how you change your Data? You must call next on the Observer and not replace the entire Observable.

Comment: Sorry for such a long delay... this thing is still bugging me. : )

Some additional info: The change detector problems I was having seem to be related to the fact that I'm using SignalR as a data source, and the SignalR javascript runs outside the Angular Zone. 

So... when I wrap my code inside a zone.run, the changes refresh as you would expect.

Comment: BUT... now I'm having big memory leak problems with the grid. My req's force me to update the data (either via an observable or directly with a GridResult array) periodically, and have fairly large data sets (100-300 rows per update every 5-10 seconds).

When I do this, the memory heap creaps up until I eventually get an "aww snap" memory error in Chrome. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've done with observables using the asyn pipe, without observables and manually assigning an array every 5 seconds... but whenever the grid updates, the chrome memory heap increases.

Comment: One final comment. I don't know why, but the memory leak issue I see with the grid happens when you run angular in debug mode. It happens with the stock demos too, not just my app.

Comment: The good thing there is that it works fine when you are in production mode. :)